# C++11: Algorithm & data structure separation

Tags: c++11, move-semantics

I have the following basic class structure:

```
class Distance : public Base {

public:
  using Base::Base;

  void run(int u, int v); // indices for nodes in graph
  void runAll();
};
```

and

```
class Base {
protected:
  const Graph& G;
  Matrix& results;

public:
  explicit Base(const Graph& G, Matrix& results);

  virtual ~Base() = default;

  virtual void run(int u, int v) = 0;
  virtual void runAll() = 0;

  double getResult(int u, int v) const;

  const Matrix& getResults() const;
};
```

where `Distance` basically calculates either for a node-pair (u, v) or for all possible node-pairs a distance-score which gets stored in the results `Matrix`.

The problem right now is the separation of the algorithm and the data structure. If I want to reuse the `run`-method of `Distance` in a second class `AnotherDistance` derived from `Base` I have to allocated the matrix 2 times (1 in `Distance` and 1 in `AnotherDistance`) which is not feasible in my case as the matrix could amount to multiple GB.

What would be the best approach to solve this? I could take the results-Matrix as an argument in the constructor (probably bad design) or maybe use move-semantics in another separate getter which would empty the matrix in the class.

Comment: Do you need Distance and AnotherDistance to share the same space for result Matrix? If so, I'll make Distance a stand-alone class that manages Matrix and make run() and runAll() to accept objects derived from Base.